# 1990s paperback with a recently divorced woman plagued by a stalker and a paranormal presence

Tags: story-identification, novel

This was another one of those paperbacks I borrowed from a girl in middle school, around 1992 or so. The main character was a recently divorced woman moving into an apartment. I think that the ex had been abusive in some way and she'd obtained a restraining order. Initially, things go well for her. The neighbors are friendly, particularly a kind of geeky guy nearby her. But after a while, she starts receiving packages from a stalker who claims they're always watching her, someone keeps smashing in her windows with no trace of how, she's got a feeling of extreme dread and the presence of something otherworldly when she visits the laundry room, and she finds the stray kitten she adopted dead, with its eyes clawed out. I remember that she suspected her ex for a while, but something happened that proved to her that it could not have been him.

I do remember a decent amount of the ending:

> It turns out that the geeky neighbor is the one stalking her. He'd devised some sort of sonic weapon, which he was using to try to make her scared enough to run to him. The shattered windows were the result of high frequencies and the feeling of an otherworldly presence was the result of subsonics. I want to say that he indicated that the kitten had been a mistake as he hadn't realized what it would do to a creature with more sensitive hearing.

### Revision

I previously thought that this book involved receiving a record of Sting's "Every Breath You Take", but I've since learned that memory is from Orson Scott Card's *Lost Boys*.

> It was a strange kind of love song. No matter what the woman did, the man
>   would be there watching her. It didn't sound like he loved her, either. Or
>   even liked her. It talked about her faking smiles, staking claims, breaking
>   promises. And the rhyming was relentless. "Every cake you bake," she thought,
>   and almost laughed. "Every child you wake. Every thirst you slake. Every duck
>   and drake. Every well-done steak." Amazing the number of words in English that
>   rhymed with take. The songwriter had barely scratched the surface.
>   Then it didn't seem funny anymore. Because somebody had sent that record to
>   them anonymously. Why would they do that? They wanted to send a message. And
>   what was the message? That no matter what they did, somebody would be
>   watching.

Comment: Is this even actually science fiction? It sounds interesting, but a lot like real science. It is possible to shatter windows with sound, and infrasound really can cause psychological effects in some people.

Comment: @Adamant: The site includes fantasy, and by that covers supernatural horror movies, as well. Not sure whether there is already a decision on whether seemingly supernatural horror, which, in a "twist ending", turns out to have quite a mundane explanation, is in scope.

Comment: Exactly, there's nothing supernatural there.

Comment: @Adamant: Neither is there if all of the supernatural happenings in a work turn out to be a dream or a hallucination, yet works where that is the case are on-topic as per [a meta question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3450/21137).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - That's because even if the story is embedded in another narrative, it is clearly fantasy. But there's no embedded story here, just a creepy mystery a la Nancy Drew or the Hardy Boys.

Comment: @Adamant: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say. Why should the existence or absence of a meta-narrative have a bearing on whether a given work is in scope for this site?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96596/discussion-between-adamant-and-o-r-mapper).

Comment: @Adamant: I'm afraid I cannot access chat at my current location. I can respond there in a couple of weeks if I can still find this question/thread by then.

Comment: @Adamant: For now, I have posted a [question on meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12628/21137) to ask about on-topic-ness.

Comment: Incidentally, [I found the book in question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/26061/novel-about-a-recently-divorced-mother-who-is-being-stalked-and-harrassed-inclu) and it is indeed not science fiction.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I don't at all remember the ending to this book, but the beginning with the divorced woman and the cat dying seemed to ring a bell with me. Could it be [Night Stalker](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9595589-night-stalker)? Alexandra Carlson is a divorced female artist who has just moved to a house in Reno, when suddenly anonymous phone calls start and her cat turns up dead.

Comment: That looks very likely. I'll have to find a copy to confirm it, but you have my upvote from the start.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you arrive at it via a search, or had you read it before?

Comment: Bit of both. I found the title via search, but I was pretty sure that if I hadn't read the book you were describing (I don't remember the sonic thing), I remembered something very similar. I think I picked it up from a charity shop when I was a kid.

Comment: Finished the book. I'm sorry, but it's not the right one. I may check out the other books she wrote, though. Apparently, most of them have very similar plots.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. :-(

Comment: :) It's one more book that I can note as not being the right one, and it really was a close match in some ways.